# String formatting specific width

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings which I want to be formatted like this:

```
XXXXX : YYYY
```

The main point is that XXXXX will be at most 5 characters long, and YYYY will be at most 7 characters long. YYYY needs to be aligned to the right, XXXXX be aligned to the left. I'm really confused and not sure how to proceed with this, can someone help me?

Should I make 2 different strings, XXXX and YYYY, align them left/right, then concatenate them into 1 string with the wanted constant length?

Comment: Care to provide any code? Things that you've tried?

Answer (score 3):

This is easy done with [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string x = "Mark";
string y = "John";

// Added Pipes to show the spaces provided by the composite format string
Console.WriteLine("|{0,-5}| : |{1,7}|", x, y);
```

Of course, when you display this output it will be meaningful only if you use a fixed pitch font. With proportional fonts, the space character is less wide than the other characters and thus your string will never be correctly aligned.

So, if you really want to show this data on video with a proportional font, it is better to use a control that provides the concept of Columns like the DataGridView, ListView and so on.

Comment: Or we can use the new string interpolation in C# 6

Comment: @EmpereurAiman good point, why don't you add an answer showing this feature?

Answer (score -3):

How do you input XXXXX and YYYY? With two different strings? Then you can use concat after substring():

```
string x = "XXXX"; string y = "YYYY";
int i = 0; j = 0;
if (x.Lengh>5){i = 5;} else {i = x.Lengh;}
if (y.Lengh>7){j = 7;} else {j = y.Lengh;}
string z = x.substring(0,i) + " : " + y.substring(0,j);
```